# Find definite integral of functions

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x t}{cos (x^{3/2})} dx $$

I tried finding the integral of the above by integration by parts, but couldn't get to the solution. Any tip to solve this one?

Comment: Is there any reason to think it has a nice solution?  Maple does this in terms of Bessel functions $I_{1/3}$ and $I_{2/3}$, along with a hypergeometric ${}_2F_2$.

Comment: yes maple provides with this ans. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are trying to solve:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right):=\int_0^\infty\exp\left(-x\text{s}\right)\cos\left(x^\text{n}\right)\space\text{d}x\tag1$$

Which can be written as a [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform):

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\cos\left(x^\text{n}\right)\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag2$$

Using:

$$\cos x=\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\cdot x^{2\text{k}}\tag3$$

So:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right)=\mathscr{L}_x\left[\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\cdot\left(x^\text{n}\right)^{2\text{k}}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}=\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\cdot\mathscr{L}_x\left[x^{2\text{kn}}\right]_{\left(\text{s}\right)}\tag4$$

Using the [table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) of selected Laplace transforms:

$$\mathcal{I}_\text{n}\left(\text{s}\right)=\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\cdot\frac{\left(2\text{kn}\right)!}{\text{s}^{1+2\text{kn}}}\tag5$$

---

So, for your case:

$$\mathcal{I}_\frac{3}{2}\left(\text{s}\right)=\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\cdot\frac{\left(2\text{k}\cdot\frac{3}{2}\right)!}{\text{s}^{1+2\text{k}\cdot\frac{3}{2}}}=\sum_{\text{k}\space\ge\space0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^\text{k}}{\text{s}^{1+3\text{k}}}\cdot\frac{\left(3\text{k}\right)!}{\left(2\text{k}\right)!}\tag6$$

Comment: Does that converge?